# Compute ascending functions

Tags: combinatorics

I want to compute ascending functions from $\lbrace 1,2,3,4,5,6 \rbrace$ to $\lbrace 1,2,3,4,5,6 \rbrace$ such that $|f(i) - i| \leq 1$, I think we should define recurrence relation like $ a_{n}=b_{n} +c_{n}  $ according to $f(1)=1$ or $f(1)=2$, but i don't know what is the relation between  $b_{n}$ and $c_{n} $

Answer (score 1):

For each $1\le i \le n$, there are three possibibilities for $f(i)$; it is either High, Medium, or Low. So you are counting sequences of $n$ letters, each in $\{L,M,H\}$, such that

1. No $H$ is followed immediately by an $L$,
2. The first letter is not $L$,
3. The last letter is not $H$.

Let $a_n$ be the numbers of sequences satisfying condition $1$ only. It is almost true that $a_n=3a_{n-1}$. However, we must subtract out the bad sequences which end with $HL$. We get that 
$$
a_n=3a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}
$$
with the base cases $a_1=3$, $a_2=8$.

Finally, we must subtract out the sequences which either end with $H$ or begin with $L$. Letting $b_n$ be the number of sequences satisfying all three rules,
$$
b_n=a_n-2a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}
$$
This means that $b_n$ satisfies the same recurrence as $a_n$, but with different initial conditions, $b_1=1,b_2=3$.